# Twixtor like slow motion iOS

Tags: ios, animation, image-processing, uiimage

Twixtor is software that turns normal video into ultra realistic slow motion by artificially creating frames. Ive done some research on how to synthesize in between frames but cannot find anything useful. My end goal is to take two UIIamges and make an in between image. Any pointers to articles or books on this subject would very helpful! I'm so lost I don't even know what to search for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to look up [Optical Flow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_flow). In fact, if you do some research, you'll find papers by [Litwinowicz](http://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&q=litwinowicz&btnG=&as_sdt=1%2C5&as_sdtp=) (who wrote Twixtor).

Comment: Yes! This is exactly the kind of thing I was looking for thank you!